# SimpleXMLElement To PHP Variables

Tags: php, xml

I have been trying to get the `Amount` from the `LandedPrice` area of this XML that was returned. I have tried this and other code that looks similar. Would anyone have any suggestions of how I would grab that information from this?

```
$simplexml = new SimpleXMLElement($response); // Is response from server.
$amount = (string) $simplexml->CompetitivePrice[0]->LandedPrice->Price->Amount;


SimpleXMLElement Object 
( [GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
    ( [@attributes] => Array ( [ASIN] => B00H9M9B34 [status] => Success ) [Product] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
        ( [Identifiers] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
            ( [MarketplaceASIN] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                ( [MarketplaceId] => ATVPDKIKX0DER [ASIN] => B00H9M9B34 ) 
            ) [CompetitivePricing] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
            ( [CompetitivePrices] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
            ( [CompetitivePrice] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                ( [@attributes] => Array ( [belongsToRequester] => false [condition] => New [subcondition] => New ) [CompetitivePriceId] => 1 [Price] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                ( [LandedPrice] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                    ( [CurrencyCode] => USD [Amount] => 75.00 ) [ListingPrice] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                    ( [CurrencyCode] => USD [Amount] => 75.00 ) [Shipping] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                    ( [CurrencyCode] => USD [Amount] => 0.00 ) 
                ) 
                ) 
            ) [NumberOfOfferListings] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                ( [OfferListingCount] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 ) ) 
            ) [SalesRankings] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
            ( [SalesRank] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                ( [ProductCategoryId] => sports_display_on_website [Rank] => 625877 ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    )
    [ResponseMetadata] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
    ( [RequestId] => 234234343d-bawff3f3-vef5555rrer) 
)
```

Comment: What does the XML look like?

Comment: Show content of `$response` variable (`echo $response`)

Comment: Its coming back from amazon apis using curl, when I do print_r($simplexml); That is what it gives me.

Comment: When I echo $response it shows this:     ATVPDKIKX0DERB001539BCE1USD171.99USD171.99USD0.002USD136.22USD136.22USD0.00171115automotive_display_on_website17012wireless_display_on_website3117524077620116021c4e9ba-2899-fw4w-4rw4r-f05a888a262d

Comment: With SimpleXML it is crucial you output the XML to yourself, and then you operate on it as outlined in the [SimpleXML Basic Usage Examples](http://www.php.net//manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). For more specific things, we have tons of good examples as well in the Q&A already.